# Emptylist issues when using parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Here is some of the code which is causing some very strange errors depending on what is 
parsed after the token emptyList in the target file.

```
data Express = Seq [Express]
              | ID String
              | Num Integer
              | BoolConst Bool
              | EmptyList String

emptyList :: Parser Express
emptyList = fmap EmptyList (string "[]")
```

The issue is:

When the string "[]" is followed by anything (including whitespace) other than a digit or the end of the file it causes the following error

```
(line 1, column 6):
unexpected end of input   OR    unexpected "d"
expecting digit
*** Exception: user error (parse error)
```

However when parsed with a digit following the [] it reports no error.

```
e.g. "[] "  error 
     "[] a" error
     "[] 1" successful
```

Also should the Num Integer be removed from the data definition and elsewhere in the file

```
number :: Parser Express
number = fmap Num integer
```

The file will parse fine without anything after the "[]" however parsing will return only up until the first occurrence of "[]" and nothing after it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to see more of your code. How is `emptyList` used? What are the other parsers it's used with?

Comment: You should post the rest of your parser code as well. I don't think the problem is in the pieces you've included so far.

Comment: The problem is with the parser that calls `emptyList`. Apparently it assumes that is either directly followed by `eof` or a `number`. Post that parser so we can diagnose the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from the way that the expressions were being delimited, whiteSpace was not being accounted for correctly when dealing with multiple expressions. 
initially:

```
seqOfExpr8 =        
    do list <- (sepBy1 expr8 (string "" ) ) 
       return $ if length list == 1 then head list else Seq list
```

fixed:

```
seqOfExpr8 =        
    do list <- (sepBy1 expr8 whiteSpace ) 
       return $ if length list == 1 then head list else Seq list
```

where whiteSpace is a lexeme parser from genTokenParser Type.